# How to recover from System.Data.Linq.DuplicateKeyException without disposing DataContext?

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql

By design I'm expecting a DuplicateKeyExeception from time to time.
Is it possible to recover from such situation without recreating the Datacontext?

Ideally I would like to remove all records that have duplicated key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387001.aspx) looks good for update conflicts.  But you have insert conflicts...

```
Customer customer = new Customer(){Name="Bob"}
myDC.Customers.InsertOnSubmit(customer);
try
{
  SubmitChanges();
}
catch(DuplicateKeyException)
{
  //throw away my old Bob and get me the database's version.
  myDC.Refresh(RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues, customer);
}
```